# Eclipse plugin / JDOM2 to slow ? "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The Eclipse Plug-in with an table view sometimes gets:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

On my desktop PC with an SSD, this happens only 10% of the time, at my work computer with an normal HDD this happens all the time. The view has an contend provider which reads in and XML file with JDOM2. By debuging I traced back the error to the following lines:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(); 
Document doc = builder.build(file);
Element element = doc.getRootElement();
```

where it receives an IOException at the secound? I'm pretty sure the file exists, since also the Plugin works sometimes.

**Update:**
To double check I edited my IOExecption:

```
catch (IOException e) { 
    if(file.length()==0){
        System.out.println("error: the following file could not be found.");
        System.out.println("File:"+file);
    }else
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

If I use a file string which is not accessable on the system the System out is used, in case the file exists the printStackTrace is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh,
I figured it out. The SAXBuilder - checks the dtd which is within the XML over the internet.

```
<!DOCTYPE annotation  SYSTEM "http://www.xyz.com/xyz.dtd">
```

The problem on my work machine is a proxy server, the one at home probally was some connection timeout, so it worked sometimes.

I was wondering why the SAXBuilder would access the Internet via http, which is clear by now.